# Music not in sequential order with Banshee

Tags: 12.04, banshee, gtk

I was looking in to Banshee Media Player as a all in one music / video player, and in general it works great (even HD films), except for one very annoying thing my music is not listed by track number or any kind of file system that I can see, it just seems to list the tracks in a random order.

This is very annoying as many albums play in a preferred order and some just sound wrong played in a random order, this is also true of the videos playlist as this is not listed alphabetically making navigation difficult.

I finished using rhythm box for the same reason years ago and used Amarok instead which did not have the issue.

So I am asking if anyone else has this issue ? or knows a fix ?, also is this a GTK issue as Amarok works fine but is a KDE app ?

[image: You can see here how messed up it is]

Comment: Thanks man I cant believe it was something so stupid repost this as an answer to get your rep and so can be closed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click the Numbers row, so it is sorted by track number.

Comment: In Ubuntu 13 clicking on the row is ordering the songs by interpreting the numbers as letters meaning "1,10,12,13,2,21"...how can I fix this